# AWS CloudFormation template for sample PHP application on Beanstalk is failing

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am deploying a PHP application to ElasticBeanstalk. First, I am deploying a sample PHP application.

This is my template.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'AWS CloudFormation Sample Template ElasticBeanstalk_PHP_Sample: Configure
  and launch the AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP sample application. **WARNING** This template
  creates one or more Amazon EC2 instances. You will be billed for the AWS resources
  used if you create a stack from this template.'
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the AWS Elastic
      Beanstalk instance
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '255'
    AllowedPattern: "[\\x20-\\x7E]*"
    ConstraintDescription: can contain only ASCII characters.
Resources:
  webApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP Sample Application
      ApplicationVersions:
        - VersionLabel: Initial Version
          Description: Version 1.0
          SourceBundle:
            S3Bucket:
              Fn::Join:
                - "-"
                - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
                  - Ref: AWS::Region
            S3Key: php-sample.zip
      ConfigurationTemplates:
        - TemplateName: DefaultConfiguration
          Description: Default Configuration Version 1.0 - with SSH access
          SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running PHP 7.3
          OptionSettings:
            - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
              OptionName: EC2KeyName
              Value:
                Ref: KeyName
  testEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: webApplication
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running PHP Sample Application
      TemplateName: DefaultConfiguration
      VersionLabel: Initial Version
Outputs:
  URL:
    Description: URL of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment
    Value:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - http://
          - Fn::GetAtt:
              - testEnvironment
              - EndpointURL
```

When I deploy executing the command in the terminal, it is failing. This is the logs.

```
{
    "StackEvents": [
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "cb6d7aa0-cdf6-11ea-b52a-0af573e17780", 
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:44:04.668Z", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "webApplication-DELETE_COMPLETE-2020-07-24T21:44:04.000Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:44:04Z", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP Sample Application\",\"ApplicationVersions\":[{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"php-sample.zip\"}}],\"ConfigurationTemplates\":[{\"Description\":\"Default Configuration Version 1.0 - with SSH access\",\"OptionSettings\":[{\"Value\":\"MyanEat\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"EC2KeyName\"}],\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\",\"SolutionStackName\":\"64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running PHP 7.3\"}]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk-webApplication-197H2GUL24WJ7", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "webApplication"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "webApplication-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-24T21:43:33.166Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:43:33.166Z", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP Sample Application\",\"ApplicationVersions\":[{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"php-sample.zip\"}}],\"ConfigurationTemplates\":[{\"Description\":\"Default Configuration Version 1.0 - with SSH access\",\"OptionSettings\":[{\"Value\":\"MyanEat\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"EC2KeyName\"}],\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\",\"SolutionStackName\":\"64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running PHP 7.3\"}]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk-webApplication-197H2GUL24WJ7", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "webApplication"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "testEnvironment-DELETE_COMPLETE-2020-07-24T21:43:32.486Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:43:32.486Z", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ApplicationName\":\"CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk-webApplication-197H2GUL24WJ7\",\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running PHP Sample Application\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "Clou-test-2HSOCMRY8B2", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "testEnvironment"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "testEnvironment-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-24T21:43:31.824Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:43:31.824Z", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ApplicationName\":\"CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk-webApplication-197H2GUL24WJ7\",\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running PHP Sample Application\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "Clou-test-2HSOCMRY8B2", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "testEnvironment"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "b5e05bd0-cdf6-11ea-80b1-062b1cfafef6", 
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:43:28.511Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [testEnvironment]. . Rollback requested by user.", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "testEnvironment-CREATE_FAILED-2020-07-24T21:43:27.905Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:43:27.905Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Environment failed to launch as it entered Terminated state", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ApplicationName\":\"CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk-webApplication-197H2GUL24WJ7\",\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running PHP Sample Application\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "Clou-test-2HSOCMRY8B2", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "testEnvironment"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "testEnvironment-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-24T21:42:57.297Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:42:57.297Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ApplicationName\":\"CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk-webApplication-197H2GUL24WJ7\",\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running PHP Sample Application\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "Clou-test-2HSOCMRY8B2", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "testEnvironment"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "testEnvironment-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-24T21:42:55.237Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:42:55.237Z", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ApplicationName\":\"CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk-webApplication-197H2GUL24WJ7\",\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running PHP Sample Application\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "testEnvironment"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "webApplication-CREATE_COMPLETE-2020-07-24T21:42:53.537Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:42:53.537Z", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP Sample Application\",\"ApplicationVersions\":[{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"php-sample.zip\"}}],\"ConfigurationTemplates\":[{\"Description\":\"Default Configuration Version 1.0 - with SSH access\",\"OptionSettings\":[{\"Value\":\"MyanEat\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"EC2KeyName\"}],\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\",\"SolutionStackName\":\"64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running PHP 7.3\"}]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk-webApplication-197H2GUL24WJ7", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "webApplication"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "webApplication-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-24T21:42:51.643Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:42:51.643Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP Sample Application\",\"ApplicationVersions\":[{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"php-sample.zip\"}}],\"ConfigurationTemplates\":[{\"Description\":\"Default Configuration Version 1.0 - with SSH access\",\"OptionSettings\":[{\"Value\":\"MyanEat\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"EC2KeyName\"}],\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\",\"SolutionStackName\":\"64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running PHP 7.3\"}]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk-webApplication-197H2GUL24WJ7", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "webApplication"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk/9a32a280-cdf6-11ea-8a9a-0aa806e28382", 
            "EventId": "webApplication-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-24T21:42:51.125Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-24T21:42:51.125Z", 
            "StackName": "CloudFormationLaravelBeanstalk", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP Sample Application\",\"ApplicationVersions\":[{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"VersionLabel\":\"Initial Version\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"php-sample.zip\"}}],\"ConfigurationTemplates\":[{\"Description\":\"Default Configuration Version 1.0 - with SSH access\",\"OptionSettings\":[{\"Value\":\"MyanEat\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"EC2KeyName\"}],\"TemplateName\":\"DefaultConfiguration\",\"SolutionStackName\":\"64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running PHP 7.3\"}]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "webApplication"
        }, 
        {
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to **verify** the issue and deploy your template on my sandbox account.

I found that the deployment fails due to **missing instance profile** in `ConfigurationTemplates`:

```
            - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
              OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
              Value: !Ref MyInstanceProfile
```

Thus you have to create [AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-instanceprofile.html) with IAM role that your EB instances will have. In basic form you could do:

```
  MyInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:                   
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Description: Beanstalk EC2 role
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier

  MyInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties: 
      Roles: 
        - !Ref MyInstanceRole
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin. This is just another question of ElasticBeanstalk with CloudFomration. How can I explicitly set the VPC for ElasticBeanstalk? I cannot find the option in the doc either. Is it even possible?

Comment: @WaiYanHein You can't do this for existing EB. Have to create new EB environment. You specify it in [options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-ec2vpc).

Comment: OK. That is what I am after. Thanks.

Comment: @WaiYanHein No problem :-)